# wired output of a bigger macro construct

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I work on a logging mechanism using macros:

```
#define LOGFATAL 1 // very serious errors
#define TOSTRING(s) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >((std::ostringstream() << s ) ).str()

#define LOG_TRANSFER(t, s) "[" << t << "] " << s

void inline print_log(const char *level, const std::string& value)
{
    std::cout << "[" << timestamp() << "]["<< level << "]" << value << std::endl;
}

#ifdef DEBUGGING
    #define DEBUG_OUT(l, s) print_log(l, TOSTRING(s));
#else
    #define DEBUG_OUT(s, l)
#endif


#if DEBUGGING >= LOGFATAL
    #define LOG_FATAL(s)        DEBUG_OUT("FATAL", s)
#else
    #define LOG_FATAL(s)
#endif
```

I use it his way:
    LOG_TRACE(LOG_TRANSFER(ptr, "MemoryManager > allocate "))
    LOG_TRACE("MemoryManager > size : " << active_list.size() )

What gcc does is:

```
print_log("TRACE", dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >((std::ostringstream() << "[" << ptr << "] " << "MemoryManager > allocate " ) ).str());
print_log("TRACE", dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >((std::ostringstream() << "MemoryManager > size : " << active_list.size() ) ).str());
```

This looks ok to me but I get the following output:

```
[0 s][TRACE]0x80940d40x9988ea8] MemoryManager > allocate 
[0 s][TRACE]0x80941e01
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >((std::ostringstream() << s )).str()
```

or more precisely with this:

```
std::ostringstream() << s
```

The reason is that the expression `std::ostringstream()` is a temporary object on which you cannot call non-member overload `<<`, as all non-member `<<` overloads take first argument as `std::ostream&`, which is non-const reference. But a temporary cannot be bound to non-const reference. Hence, a member function is called when you want to print `char*`, which gets converted into `void*` and address is printed.

You need to do a little hack. Convert the temporary object (rvalue) into a reference type (lvalue) as:

```
std::ostringstream().flush() << s
```

**Why would I call `flush()` like that??**

Well you can call a member function on a temporary object. I chose `flush()` because it returns `std::ostream&` which is non-const reference, and which is what we need.

The difference it makes is this:

```
std::ostringstream() << "nawaz" ; //it prints the address of "nawaz".
std::ostringstream().flush() << "nawaz" ; //it prints "nawaz"
```

The first one calls the member `operator<<` which prints the address, the second one call the non-member `operator<<` which prints the c-string. That is the difference behind the scene.

So try this:

```
dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >((std::ostringstream().flush() << s )).str()
```

That should work.

Also, I would suggest `static_cast` here, as you know the type already:

```
static_cast< std::ostringstream & >((std::ostringstream().flush() << s )).str()
```

It doesn't depend on RTTI.

Comment: Nice explanation of rvalue conversion -- I hadn't realized the .flush() trick to fix it when I ran into this problem myself.